# Excel VBA: VBA code not picking up data in CSV file

Tags: excel, csv, ms-word, vba

My current code reads as follows:

```
LastRow = WB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count  
'...
For irow = 6 To LastRow
            WordFile.Tables(1).Cell(irow, 7).Range.Text = WB.Sheets(1).Cells(irow, 22)   
Next
```

My CSV file opens up with data in it's designated columns so i don't need to seperate data. However, my code doesn't seem to be reading any data in my CSV file. Lastrow keeps coming out to 1, no matter what method i use (there's 10 rows of data). When the code runs with no errors, the cells in my word table are still blank. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you're opening the file you think you're opening?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I opened the csv file in excel and run the vba code from there. which opens a word file to move the csv data into.

Comment: If its returning 1 you might be calling the wrong workbook. what is `WB` ? did you try using `LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count` ?

Comment: Only 1 WB open and yes i did try thisworkbook. I thought that was the problem so i set set WB to ThisWorkbook.